# Speeding calculations

Tags: vba, vb6

With some 20K observations, the following code takes some 7.5 sec to run

```
'Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer
For i = 2 To UBound(avTransposed, 2)
    For J = 1 To UBound(avTransposed, 1)
        k = IIf(J = 1, k + 1, k)
        '                    If J = 1 Then k = k + 1
        ReDim Preserve TrueUsedRangeArray(1 To Dim2, 1 To k)
        TrueUsedRangeArray(J, k) = avTransposed(J, i)
    Next
Next
'Determine how many seconds code took to run
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
```

Without the
**k = IIf(J = 1, k + 1, k)** line (or  **If J = 1 Then k = k + 1**),  it takes less than one sec!!

Any idea?

Comment: As a result of testing with 400,000 data, it took 0.12 seconds. There seems to be a cause other than a code problem. You will need to have more specifics about your data to find the cause. If there are formulas related to the cell, it may be slow.

Comment: Dim2 runs from 1 to 33. K runs from 1 to 20000.
avTransposed is a variant array. No formulas

Comment: result of testing of your data, it took 0.41 seconds

Comment: The `IIf` is inherently slower than a normal `if`/`else` as it must evaluate and store `k + 1` even if  `J` is not `1` - but that is a tiny difference that would not lead to the huge discrepancy there evidently is.

Comment: The variables `k` and `Dim2` are not initialized before being used, at least as shown in the posted code snippet.  It's not possible to fully understand the array usage (and thus the array resizing, and thus possible performance impacts) without knowing how those variables are set/utilized.

Answer (score 4):

The ReDim Preserve is probably killing performance. Every time it is used, it creates a new array and copies the existing array in.

You can work out up-front the size of TrueUsedRangeArray, something like the following

```
ReDim TrueUsedRangeArray(1 To Ubound(avTransposed, 2), 1 To Ubound(avTransposed, 1))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: This. Redim Preserve can be very slow.

Answer (score 4):

Too many things in your inner loop which do not need to be there:

```vb
For i = 2 To UBound(avTransposed, 2)
    k = k + 1
    ReDim Preserve TrueUsedRangeArray(1 To Dim2, 1 To k)
    For J = 1 To UBound(avTransposed, 1)
        TrueUsedRangeArray(J, k) = avTransposed(J, i)
    Next
Next
```

As Patrick notes though, you do not need the redim preserve in the loop, since you already know the final size of TrueUsedRangeArray from the dimensions of avTransposed